# CQ5 dispatcher- exclude specific url's from caching

Tags: apache, caching, aem

I need to exclude certain pages from caching in the dispatcher. I found [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/DispatcherNoCache.html) that a way can be to add this header in the page's . But this does not work in my page somehow.

```
<%
  response.setHeader("Dispatcher", "no-cache");
%>
```

Another solution is to append the page URL with a query param like `?v=1` but this is not suitable for a production website page

Is there a way to tell the dispatcher NOT to cache certain url's ? Probable something similar to allow/deny certain file types in the dispatcher.any ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to set some arbitrary regexp on which base you can tell whether to cache or not to cache given resource you can use the `/rules` section in the dispatcher `/cache` configuration.

Take a look at [Configuring dispatcher](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/disp-config.html#Specifying%20the%20Documents%20to%20Cache).

```
/rules
  {
   /0000  { /glob "*" /type "allow" }
   /0001  { /glob "/en/news/*" /type "deny" }
   /0002  { /glob "*/private/*" /type "deny"  }   
  }
```